# How to create a session in node.js with jade

Tags: node.js, session

I made a login for admin panel and now i want to implement the session.
I was searching alot but could not find How to implement the sessions in node.js. Simply i want to store the token when i login from admin panel and for logging out the session will be destroyed. Please help. 
Here is my login code:

```
`use strict`

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../../user/auth/storage/model/User');
const userPopulation = require('../../user/auth/storage/populate/userPopulation');
var loginServices = {};

loginServices.login = (req, res, next) => {
    // var rollno = param.rollno.toLowerCase()
    // var email = req.body.email
    // console.log(email);
    return User.findOne({ email: req.session.email })
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user)
            if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                if (user.role == 'admin') {
                    const token = authToken(user)
                    res.render('../views/home', { token: token, user: user });
                } else {
                    res.redirect('/auth/login');
                }
            }
            else {
                res.redirect('/auth/login');
                // return Promise.reject(ES.authError('Authentication Failed'))
            }
        })
}

const authToken = (user) => {
    return jwt.sign(
        {
            email: user.email,
            _id: user._id,
            role: user.role
        },
        process.env.SECRET_KEY,
        {
            expiresIn: process.env.TOKEN_EXPIRY_TIME
        }
    )
}

module.exports = loginServices;
```

Here is the snippet of app.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;


app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use(session({
    secret:'sssshhh',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    // Because Stripe needs the raw body, we compute it but only when hitting the Stripe callback URL.
    verify: function(req,res,buf) {
        var url = req.originalUrl;
        console.log('------------'+url);
        if (url.startsWith('/notify_transaction_success')) {
            req.rawBody = buf.toString();
        }
    }}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

I do alot of search but i could not find any solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I, basically, followed this step by step to get my sessions up and running with only some slight modification to how the session is stored.

https://medium.com/@evangow/server-authentication-basics-express-sessions-passport-and-curl-359b7456003d

After you are up and running, you can insert a if( req.isAuthenticated() ) into your middleware for routes and you are laughing.

Comment: Also, I didn't use cURL for testing, I just did it in the browser.

Comment: I thinks thats manage session from server side but i want to store token in client side with jade template engine @David Duffy

Comment: When you create a session, it does store a cookie on the client. You can set the terms for how long it is until expired. So, once you have authenticated, it is authenticated. Jade is an engine for quickly and cleanly producing web content.